# Riccati equation (is my answer correct?)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wanted to ask is my answer for solving Riccati equation correct.

$(dy/dx) + (y^2/x^3) + (y/(2x)) + (x/2)$, i know that partial solution of the equation is 
$y = x^2$ so i need to find general solution in terms of $y(x) = x^2 + z(x)$,
i plug $y(x) = x^2 + z$ and $(dy/dx) = 2x + z$ in the initial equation. After some algebric equation i got $(dz/z^2) - (5/2*x) * (1 / z) =$ now after substituting $u = -1/z$ i get Bernoullis equation that i know how to solve.

After doing all this i got result $z(x) = -(x^{5/2})/ (c-2/x^2) $but in the text book it says solution is $x^{5/2} / (c - 2*\sqrt{x})$. Is my answer or their answer correct?

Thank you!

Comment: xpowy is $x^y$.

Comment: I put in mathjax, but what does $(dz/z^2)-(5x/2)(1/z)$ equal?

Comment: Some typos in the question apparently. $x^{2}$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{x^{5/2}}{c - 2*\sqrt{x}}  \quad$ is solution of $\quad\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{x^3}+\frac{5y}{2x}\quad$ and is not solution of 
$\quad\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{y^2}{x^3}+\frac{y}{2x}+\frac{x}{2}=0$.

So, necessarily there is a typo.

Comment: thank you so my answer is correct?

Comment: Your answer cannot be correct because you started from a supposed known particular solution $y=x^2$. That's the hitch : $y=x^2$ is not a solution of the $(dy/dx) + (y^2/x^3) + (y/(2x)) + (x/2)=0$. In fact solving it is possible but complicated. Probably if there was no typo into it the solution would be much simpler.